# grabbing article id post

Tags: php

For some reason, this isn't working, but not sure why. I'm trying to grab the comment id on how many comments are in the database, but it's showing "0". When clearly I see comments.

Visit live: http://www.krissales.me/#/media/articles

If you click on the article link, it'll show how many comments on that page, but not on the page I want it to show on.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the:

> $amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id='" .
>   mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");         $comments =
>   mysql_num_rows($amount_get);

article.php:

```
<?php

        $amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'"); 
        $comments = mysql_num_rows($amount_get);            

        $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' LIMIT 1");    
        $grab = mysql_query("SELECT id, news_title, news_content, news_author, news_day, news_month, news_year, news_date FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC limit 3"); 
        $news_day =$row['news_day'];
        $news_month =$row['news_month'];
        $news_year =$row['news_year'];


        if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no articles posted!</div>";
    }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){

    ?>

    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post">
        <div class="left">
        <div class="date"><span class="day"><?php echo $row['news_day'] ?></span> <span class="month"><?php echo $row['news_month'] ?></span> <span class="year"><?php echo $row['news_year'] ?></span></div></div>
        <div class="postcontent"><h5 class="posttitle"><a href="#/media/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>.<?php echo stripslashes(str_replace(" ", "-", $row['news_title'])); ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($row['news_title']); ?></a></h5>                       
            <p>The content for this article will be posted here shortly, i need to edit some PHP that limits the chars for this section</p>
            <p>Comments (<?php echo $comments ?>)</p>
            </div>
    </div>​
    </div>  

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You're counting by specific ID, so I guess at most you get 1, or your ID means something else?

Comment: I think you don't have to encapsulate the id since it is a numeric value. Try without the quotes: "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ""

Comment: @MAXIM being a numeric value, mysql_real_escape_STRING is useless too. Cast it to int instead, or check if it is already

Comment: whatever is within $_GET is a string anyways, so it is ok to escape it, but when you then match it in the SQL statement generaly if the ID is numeric then encosing within the quote would mean as to tell SQL to match 'THIS string' to THAT integer. Which could fail

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the WHERE condition of this line:

```
$amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");
```

I guess that `id` should been changed to something like `article_id` - a foreign_key that points the an article.

Comment: yeah, I tried that. $amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");  but it didn't work.

Comment: Is `articleId` really the name of the column? What means 'does not work'?. Do you got an error message? What does `mysql_error()` say? (After executing the query). Can you post the (relevant) php code of the article detail page?

Comment: I'm not seeing a sql error anywhere. This is the full php http://pastebin.com/fNYSSRWk and yes, articleid is valid: http://puu.sh/1Cuh8

Comment: The code you posted to pastebin seems to be the index page. I would like to see the code from the article detail page - the code that generates the pages where comments are listed properly.

Comment: my bad, here it is. http://pastebin.com/6BB4jds5

Comment: I can see no differences between both files that should lead to the commens(0) on the index page. Have you cleared all caches after fixing the bug?

Comment: yep. I have no idea what seems to be the problem. But I do appreciate your help!